# How can I get plain text file in Flash?

Tags: flash

Which function can I use to get the content of a plain text file?

I can just read "value=32" as a variable or file in xml format now, but the file from vendor contains only the value "32".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops: Only now did I notice that you are on AS2: use `LoadVars` instead. (Got this [from here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000886.html))

```
var ldr = new LoadVars();
ldr.onData  = function (result:String) 
{
  if (success) 
  {
    trace("loaded " + result);
  }
  else
  {
    trace ("Error loading");
  }
} 
ldr.load("fileurl.txt");
```

---

The following applies only to AS3:

If the file is at your server (or a server that allows your swf to access it with a crossdomain.xml), you can load it using `URLLoader`.

```
var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoad);
ldr.load(new URLRequest("fileurl.text"));

function onLoad(e:Event):void
{
  var loadedText:String = URLLoader(e.target).data;
  var value:Number = Number(loadedText);
}
```

Comment: Given that OP states he is using AS2, this isn't a good answer.