# How can I retrieve CSV data from a web server using Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, csv

I am trying to retrieve a stock quote from Yahoo! finance using Flex. I currently have it set so that it will pull the quote like I want, but it opens it in a new file. However, I want to store the CSV data in a variable so that I can use it in my program.

How do I do this?

Here is the code that I am using right now:

```
navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=aapl&f=l1"),"_self");
```

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605739/how-can-i-get-plain-text-file-in-flash/1606165#1606165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<mx:HTTPService id="userRequest" url="http://download.finance.yahoo.com
    /d/quotes.csv?s=aapl&f=l1" useProxy="false" method="POST" resultFormat="object"
 result="{resultEvent(event)}">

public function init() {
      userRequest.send()      
}

public function resultEvent(event:ResultEvent) {

        trace(event.result);

 }
```

On your result event, trace your data.

Comment: Now I ran into a security problem :(

Comment: It's because of crossdomain.xml on yahoo, for some reason I cannot access it. It says something along the lines of "Denied access because of policy file" It seems like the technique is to pull the data from the website using something like PHP to avoid Flash security problems and then read that data locally from Flex. Does that seem right?

Comment: No, you can read the data without doing anything you have commented. Have you placed crossdomain.xml in your root path. 

http://search.yahooapis.com/crossdomain.xml

Yahoo's crossdomain.xml should allow you retrieve data from their services.

Answer (score 3):

navigateToURL will open a URL from within a Flex application.

Take a look at HTTPService at http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/data_access_2.html .  It should give you back the results of the HTTP call; which you can than parse and traverse at your leisure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both mxml tag `<mx:httpService>` or AS3 code (`urlRequest` and `urlLoader`), but I am afraid that the result will not change: if the problem is yahoo's `crossdomain.xml` file, or yahoo add an entry to this file or you cannot reverse data directly from yahoo finance on your flex app: I suggest you to call from your flex app  a script of yours that get data from yahoo and reverse them into your flex app.